# Default username and password of kali linux -2021.1-vbox amd 64?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I had tried this

USERNAME: Root
PASSWORD: Root

user: kali
password: kali

the version is 2021.1 64bit

help me to either update it or bypass it
what is the correct credential?

Comment: User names are case sensitive, i.e. root not Root.  No idea if there is a default.

Comment: Since 2020.1, the default credentials are `kali`/`kali`.

Comment: doesn't log in telling @Allan Wind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default username `kali` and password `kali`.

[Kali's Default Credentials](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/default-credentials/)

> Any default operating system credentials used during Live Boot, or pre-created image (like Virtual Machines & ARM) will be:

```
User: kali
Password: kali
```